# Different ways a stored procedure returns data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetSalaryInfo
    @AverageSalary INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(1) MaxSalary;
    SELECT @AverageSalary = AVG(1);
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(1) Total);
END
```

When I execute the query, I get 3 result set. One from `SELECT` statement, one from `OUTPUT` parameters and the last one from `RETURN` statement.

```
DECLARE @MaximumSalary INT, @AverageSalary INT, @TotalEmployee int;

EXEC @TotalEmployee = spGetSalaryInfo @AverageSalary OUT

SELECT @AverageSalary AS AVGERAGE
SELECT @TotalEmployee AS TotalEmployee
```

**Output:**

```
MaxSalary   AVGERAGE    TotalEmployee
----------- ----------- -------------
1           1           1
```

As you can see, I can return data by selecting `SELECT` query or `OUTPUT` parameter inside a stored procedure as well as by `return` statement.

I wonder, at what scenario we can use this type of stored procedure. I am confused a little.

Comment: I would recommend using output parameters for scalar values.  If you can, use a table-valued function if you want to return a table.

Comment: Relevant article: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: Output parameters, result sets and return values each have their own use. The return value is the least general, as it can only be a single non-null `INT`, and is thus best confined to status codes, even if you happen to only have an `INT` to return. Deciding whether to use output parameters or result sets is less straightforward, but it's usually dictated by the shape of your data and what your callers can handle. (In particular, if your caller is [another stored procedure](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html), things get interesting.)

Comment: a RETURN value can only give back one integer value. some folks use this as a type of return status like if a SP failed, or some other status. output parameters can be used to give back single values you need, but can be of any data type. the SELECT statement will give back a dataset of rows and columns, of which there could be just one row and one column, but is designed for table type data.

Comment: @Alejandro Useful article.

Comment: @Jeremy ya. now I understand.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Useful information. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of an odd way to return three variables from a stored procedure, the typical case would choose to either return all three as output parameters, or all three as columns of a single-row result.

> I wonder, at what scenario we can use this type of stored procedure. I am confused a little.

In most cases a select statement will return a *set* of data (i.e one with many rows for a set of columns) but in certain cases (of which this looks like one) you just have some discreet values and not a set of values.

Answer (score -2):

Why didn't you try like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetSalaryInfo
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
         @TotalEmployee INT
        ,@MaxSalary INT

    SELECT @MaxSalary  = MAX(1)
    SELECT @AverageSalary = AVG(1)
    SELECT @TotalEmployee = COUNT(1)

    SELECT 
         @MaxSalary AS MaxSalary
        ,@AverageSalary AS AVGERAGE
        ,@TotalEmployee  AS TotalEmployee  
END
```

Comment: That doesn't return anything. Those local scalar variables are NOT output parameters.

Comment: You do not need to use an output parameter, You should just return a dataset.